# weblogic.socket.DevPollSocketMuxer.processSockets locking so long

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, weblogic

Would you advise me, what was happen here? I found that this thread#3 is locking current object and wont release it for so long. This is causing the rest of the threads are waiting this object until it released.

```
"ExecuteThread: '3' for queue: 'weblogic.socket.Muxer'" daemon prio=10 tid=01df3780 nid=67 lwp_id=6827871 runnable [4f7c0000..4f7c0cd0]

    at weblogic.socket.DevPollSocketMuxer.doPoll(Native Method)
    at weblogic.socket.DevPollSocketMuxer.processSockets(DevPollSocketMuxer.java:96)-locked <75800758> (a java.lang.String)
    at weblogic.socket.SocketReaderRequest.run(SocketReaderRequest.java:29)
    at weblogic.socket.SocketReaderRequest.execute(SocketReaderRequest.java:42)
    at weblogic.kernel.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:145)
    at weblogic.kernel.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:117) 

"ExecuteThread: '4' for queue: 'weblogic.socket.Muxer'" daemon prio=10 tid=01df3970 nid=68 lwp_id=6827872 waiting for monitor entry [4f6c0000..4f6c0d50]

    at weblogic.socket.DevPollSocketMuxer.processSockets(DevPollSocketMuxer.java:93)
- waiting to lock <75800758> (a java.lang.String)
    at weblogic.socket.SocketReaderRequest.run(SocketReaderRequest.java:29)
    at weblogic.socket.SocketReaderRequest.execute(SocketReaderRequest.java:42)
    at weblogic.kernel.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:145)
    at weblogic.kernel.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:117)

"ExecuteThread: '2' for queue: 'weblogic.socket.Muxer'" daemon prio=10 tid=01df3590 nid=66 lwp_id=6827870 waiting for monitor entry [4f8c0000..4f8c0c50]

    at weblogic.socket.DevPollSocketMuxer.processSockets(DevPollSocketMuxer.java:93)
- waiting to lock <75800758> (a java.lang.String)
    at weblogic.socket.SocketReaderRequest.run(SocketReaderRequest.java:29)
    at weblogic.socket.SocketReaderRequest.execute(SocketReaderRequest.java:42)
    at weblogic.kernel.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:145)
    at weblogic.kernel.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:117)

"ExecuteThread: '1' for queue: 'weblogic.socket.Muxer'" daemon prio=10 tid=01df33a0 nid=65 lwp_id=6827869 waiting for monitor entry [4f9c0000..4f9c0bd0]

    at weblogic.socket.DevPollSocketMuxer.processSockets(DevPollSocketMuxer.java:93)
- waiting to lock <75800758> (a java.lang.String)
    at weblogic.socket.SocketReaderRequest.run(SocketReaderRequest.java:29)
    at weblogic.socket.SocketReaderRequest.execute(SocketReaderRequest.java:42)
    at weblogic.kernel.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:145)
    at weblogic.kernel.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:117)

"ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.socket.Muxer'" daemon prio=10 tid=01df31b0 nid=64 lwp_id=6827868 waiting for monitor entry [4fac0000..4fac0b50]

    at weblogic.socket.DevPollSocketMuxer.processSockets(DevPollSocketMuxer.java:93)
- waiting to lock <75800758> (a java.lang.String)
    at weblogic.socket.SocketReaderRequest.run(SocketReaderRequest.java:29)
    at weblogic.socket.SocketReaderRequest.execute(SocketReaderRequest.java:42)
    at weblogic.kernel.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:145)
    at weblogic.kernel.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:117)
```